# javascript - How do I use regex to match the following string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am kind of new to regex, and haven't used it much before.

I am trying to match the following string `String A` and replace it to `String B`

String A:

```
+ ANYTHING_NO_SPACES.prototype.ANYTHING_NO_SPACES = function()
{
    ANYTHING
}
```

String B:

```
ANYTHING_NO_SPACES.prototype.function_segments.ANYTHING_NO_SPACES.push(function())
{
    ANYTHING
})
```

`ANYTHING_NO_SPACES` means anything can be put there with no spaces

`ANYTHING` means anything can be put there, spaces etc.

I also would like to ignore new lines, so a new line would be the same thing as a space or nothing.

**EDIT:** Here's what I've got so far:

```
(\+ \w+.prototype\.\w+ = function\(\)( |\n){([\S\s]*?)})
```

I can't figure out how to finish the last bit.. changing to string into `string b`

Any ideas on how to finish that?

Comment: Yes, I do need to look more into regex.

Comment: I've updated the question, and I do not think it is a duplicate anymore.

Comment: OK, the fact it's multi-line and a block makes it less trivial, I'll try to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
var output = input.replace(
  /(^|\n)\s*\+\s*(\w+)\.prototype\.(\w+)\s*=\s*function\(\)\n{([\s\S]+?\n})/g,
  "$1$2.prototype.function_segments.$3.push(function())\n{$4)"
);
```

A few things worth noticeable in that regular expression:

- `(^|\n)` is either the start of the string or a new line
- `[\s\S]` matches any character including a new line
- `[\s\S]+?` is non greedy so that it doesn't capture several functions in one go
- this can work only if your code is properly indented: as the code isn't *parsed* we rely on a `}` being at the start of the line to detect the end of the function

**Demonstration:**

```js
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML.replace(
  /(^|\n)\s*\+\s*(\w+)\.prototype\.(\w+)\s*=\s*function\(\)\n{([\s\S]+?\n})/g,
  "$1$2.prototype.function_segments.$3.push(function())\n{$4)"
);
```

```html
INPUT:
<pre id=input>
+ ANYTHING_NO_SPACES.prototype.ANYTHING_NO_SPACES = function()
{
    ANYTHING
}
+ blabla.prototype.hop = function()
{
    ANYTHING
    TOO
}
</pre>
OUTPUT:
<pre id=output>
```

Comment: Just a quick question, does lazy and non greedy mean the same thing?

Comment: @DavidCallanan Yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks a million, and thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I don't know what happened there. I must have clicked it by mistake. I accepted the answer again.